# Trying to reset values of Comboboxes using a loop (GUI/Java)

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, netbeans, combobox

I'm using netbeans to make a GPA calculator that uses a series of combo boxes (5, that are exactly the same). I'm trying to reset their values to the first value after the calculator runs using a loop:

```
javax.swing.JComboBox aoComboBoxes []=new javax.swing.JComboBox [6];

    aoComboBoxes [0]= cmbxACC200;
    aoComboBoxes [1]= cmbxBUSM241;
    aoComboBoxes [2]= cmbxFIN201;
    aoComboBoxes [3]= cmbxIS110;
    aoComboBoxes [4]=cmbxIS201;
    aoComboBoxes[5]=cmbxIS303;

    for (int i=0; i<aoComboBoxes.length; i++) 
    {
        aoComboBoxes[0].setSelectedIndex(0);
    }
```

Is this possible? Right now, the code doesn't function as is and I'm not sure if that is because of an error in the way I've written the code, or if it isn't possible to do something like this. I'm more curious as to whether this is possible because I'll also want to run a loop to get the data from each combo box and assign it to a variable: 
    int iLetterGrade;

```
for (int i=0; i<aoComboBoxes.length; i++) 
{
  iLetterGrade=aoComboBoxes[0].getSelectedIndex();      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well your 1st for loop will reset the aoComboBoxes[0] 6 times only because you have hard coded the index to 0.While retrieving data you did the same mistake in 2nd for loop.

Just replace the for loops with below:

```
 for (int i=0; i<aoComboBoxes.length; i++) 
{
    aoComboBoxes[i].setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

2nd for loop:

```
 for (int i=0; i<aoComboBoxes.length; i++) 
 {
    iLetterGrade=aoComboBoxes[i].getSelectedIndex();      
 }
```

Comment: Wow. Noob mistake. My apologies. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @MalloryReese..No worries ..It happens